# How to align dynamically created cardView vertically in recyclerView?

Tags: android

I have created cardviews dynamically,but while displaying that into the recyclerview,cardviews getting displayed horizontally even though the parent linear layout orientation is vertical.

I wants to display the cardviews vertically (i.e)one card after another card,can anyone help me to address this issue?

**Adapter Class**

```
public RecyclerAdapter(HashMap<String, List<EventDataModel>> stringListHashMap, Context ctx) {

            cardViews = new ArrayList<>();
            this.stringListHashMap = stringListHashMap;
            CardView.LayoutParams cardViewParams=new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            cardViewParams.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );


            for(Map.Entry<String, List<EventDataModel>> listEntry : this.stringListHashMap.entrySet()) {
                CardView cardView = new CardView(ctx);
                cardView.setLayoutParams(cardViewParams);
                cardView.setPadding(10,5,10,5);
                cardView.setContentPadding(10,10,10,10);
                cardView.setUseCompatPadding(true);
                cardView.setCardElevation(10);
                cardView.setMaxCardElevation(15);
                cardView.setRadius(9);

                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
                layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


                for(EventDataModel eventDataModel : listEntry.getValue()) {
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
                    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    linearLayout.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    TextView textViewKey = new TextView(ctx);
                    TextView textViewValue = new TextView(ctx);
                    textViewKey.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    textViewKey.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    textViewValue.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    textViewValue.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    textViewKey.setText(eventDataModel.getKey());
                    textViewValue.setText(eventDataModel.getValue());

                    linearLayout.addView(textViewKey);
                    linearLayout.addView(textViewValue);

                    layout.addView(linearLayout);

                }

                cardView.addView(layout);
                cardViews.add(cardView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_layout, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


            Log.d("position>>",position+"");
            holder.rootLayout.addView(cardViews.get(position));
        }
```

**event_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relat"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
</LinearLayout>
```

[current cardviews display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIq7Z.png)

I have created one more linear layout dynamically to add that cardview into that layout,but its also pop up some error,because of already having the rootLayout.

Comment: you are definitely doing something very strange in your adapter constructor

Comment: @VladMatvienko yeah,I am trying to create the components in the layout dynamically,i have done something but while aligning the dynamically created components only getting issue

Comment: If I'm right, you should not create anything in adapter constructor at all. I can't see you are using any of those created views at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where you are calling adapter class on recycler. Just put this code there and try::

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false); 
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

We need to assign "LayoutManager" to recycler view to define it in which way it used to work, like "grid,staggered, list, so on" and we can also define the "scrolling". So just we defined the vertical behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @ankit patidar,its working as expected..can I know how its resolving that issue?

Comment: We need to assign "LayoutManager" to recycler view to define it in which way he use to work, like "grid,staggered, list, so on" and we can also define the "scrolling". so just we defined the vertical behaviour

Comment: yeash sure I will accept your answer,but before that I have some doubts like in my event_layout.xml file itself I have specified the orientation should be in vertical right?,why not its taking that?

Comment: Yes you specified, but its for single item of list. Like if you add some more layout other than cardview in single item. then it will shown one below another format. You understand?

Comment: yeah ankit,got it..thanks a lot for your valuable support.. @ankit patidar

Comment: Thats ok, if you need more to know. please ask me whenever you need it.

Comment: I have done ankit,I don't know why its not getting updated?

Comment: i think you have reputation less then 15, thats it can't